# How can I use older libraries in updated Python?

Tags: python

I am using Python 3.4 with PyCharm IDE. Some of the external libraries have been released for this version of Python. But most might not be presented yet, just like matplotlib.
I have you use this library. How can I use matlibplot for Python 3.3 in Python 3.4? Must I migrate again to python 3.3?!

Thank you

Comment: many of python packages support in that major version. means when a package works in python3 most of the time it supports all of python3 versions.

Comment: What happens when you try to run Matplotlib? Does it look like a simple error that we could fix?

Comment: @jforberg: Actually, there is no error generated by IDE compiler. I've just imported matplotlib 3.3 into my 3.4-driven project. As I call the older functions, I got neither the valid result nor any error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the library is pure Python then any code that runs in Python 3.3 should also run in Python 3.4.

If the library contains Python byte code (pyc) then there is [no guarantee of compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22449524/python-bytecode-compatibility). You have to recompile the Python code.

if the library contains c code ([pyd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8822335/what-does-python-file-extensions-pyc-pyd-pyo-stand-for)) then you have no guarantee of Python C API compatibility unless the library made [some specific switches for it](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/stable.html). You would have to recompile the C code.

Matplotlib falls into the latter categories. However there are version of matplotlib compiled against Python 3.4 (for [Windows](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#matplotlib)). Or you have to go back to Python 3.3.

Comment: As I think I've been encountering with pyc case probably, Would you please letting me know about the recompiling procedure?

Comment: @matinking You just delete them all. They are created automatically from the corresponding py files which must be there of course. Or you use [compile all](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/how-do-i-create-a-pyc-file.htm).